# media3 MediaSessionService dont start and crash after few seconds

Tags: android, service, exoplayer, android-mediasession, android-media3

I am trying to implement media3 mediaSessionService and play music. But service dont start, i dont see notification and after approximately 10sec app is crashing. I am using Sumsung a70 android 11.

MyMusicService.kt

```
@UnstableApi
class MyMusicService : MediaSessionService(), MediaSession.Callback {

        lateinit var exoPlayer: ExoPlayer
        lateinit var mediaSession: MediaSession


    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    override fun onCreate() {

        super.onCreate()
        Log.d("tag","----------------------------- MediaSessionService, onCreate")

        exoPlayer = ExoPlayer.Builder(this).build()
        mediaSession = MediaSession.Builder(this, exoPlayer).setCallback(this).build()


    }

    @SuppressLint("UnsafeOptInUsageError")
    private fun updateNotification(session: MediaSession): MediaNotification {

        val notify = NotificationCompat.Builder(this,"Radio")
            .setSmallIcon(R.drawable.ic_launcher_foreground)
            // This is globally changed every time when
            // I add a new MediaItem from background service
            .setContentTitle("title")
            .setContentText("artist")
            .setStyle(MediaStyleNotificationHelper.MediaStyle(session))
            .build()

        return MediaNotification(1, notify)
    }

    override fun onGetSession(controllerInfo: MediaSession.ControllerInfo): MediaSession = mediaSession

    override fun onAddMediaItems(mediaSession: MediaSession, controller: MediaSession.ControllerInfo, mediaItems: MutableList<MediaItem>): ListenableFuture<MutableList<MediaItem>> {
        val updatedMediaItems = mediaItems.map { it.buildUpon().setUri(it.mediaId).build() }.toMutableList()
        return Futures.immediateFuture(updatedMediaItems)
    }

    override fun onDestroy() {
        Log.d("tag","----------------------------- MediaSessionService, onDestroy")
        exoPlayer.stop()
        exoPlayer.release()
        mediaSession.release()
        super.onDestroy()
    }
}
```

MainActivity.kt

```
@UnstableApi class MainActivity : AppCompatActivity() {
    

    lateinit var controller: MediaController


    override fun onCreate(savedInstanceState: Bundle?) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState)
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_main)

    }

    override fun onStart() {
        super.onStart()

        val sessionToken = SessionToken(this, ComponentName(this, MyMusicService::class.java))

        val controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(this, sessionToken)
            .buildAsync()

        controllerFuture.addListener({
            findViewById<PlayerControlView>(R.id.player).player = controllerFuture.get()

        },
            MoreExecutors.directExecutor())

        controller = controllerFuture.get()
        initController()

        controller.apply {
            setMediaItem(
            MediaItem.Builder()
                .setMediaId("http://listen.vo.llnwd.net/g3/prvw/9/5/1/1/7/2489571159.mp3")
                .build()
        )

            prepare()
            play()
        }

    }


    private fun initController() {
        //controller.playWhenReady = true
        controller.addListener(object : Player.Listener {

            override fun onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata: MediaMetadata) {
                super.onMediaMetadataChanged(mediaMetadata)
                Log.d("tag","onMediaMetadataChanged=$mediaMetadata")
            }

            override fun onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying: Boolean) {
                super.onIsPlayingChanged(isPlaying)
                Log.d("tag","onIsPlayingChanged=$isPlaying")
            }

            override fun onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState: Int) {
                super.onPlaybackStateChanged(playbackState)
                Log.d("tag","onPlaybackStateChanged=?}")
            }

            override fun onPlayerError(error: PlaybackException) {
                super.onPlayerError(error)
                Log.d("tag","onPlayerError=${error.stackTraceToString()}")
            }

            override fun onPlayerErrorChanged(error: PlaybackException?) {
                super.onPlayerErrorChanged(error)
                Log.d("tag","onPlayerErrorChanged=${error?.stackTraceToString()}")
            }
        })
        Log.d("tag","start=}")
        Log.d("tag","COMMAND_PREPARE=${controller.isCommandAvailable(COMMAND_PREPARE)}")
        Log.d("tag","COMMAND_SET_MEDIA_ITEM=${controller.isCommandAvailable(COMMAND_SET_MEDIA_ITEM)}")
        Log.d("tag","COMMAND_PLAY_PAUSE=${controller.isCommandAvailable(COMMAND_PLAY_PAUSE)}")
    }
}
```

Manifest

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<manifest xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools">

    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.FOREGROUND_SERVICE"/>
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.INTERNET"/>

    <application
        android:name=".chatgptservice.App"
        android:allowBackup="true"
        android:dataExtractionRules="@xml/data_extraction_rules"
        android:fullBackupContent="@xml/backup_rules"
        android:icon="@mipmap/ic_launcher"
        android:label="@string/app_name"
        android:supportsRtl="true"
        android:theme="@style/Theme.TestApp"
        tools:targetApi="31">
        <activity
            android:name=".MainActivity"
            android:exported="true">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="android.intent.action.MAIN" />

                <category android:name="android.intent.category.LAUNCHER" />
            </intent-filter>
        </activity>

        <service
            android:name=".MyMusicService"
            android:foregroundServiceType="mediaPlayback"
            android:exported="true"
            android:enabled="true"
            tools:ignore="ExportedService">
            <intent-filter>
                <action android:name="androidx.media3.session.MediaSessionService"/>
                <action android:name="android.media.browse.MediaBrowserService"/>
            </intent-filter>
        </service>

    </application>

</manifest>
```

libs

```
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer:1.0.0-rc02"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-ui:1.0.0-rc02"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-exoplayer-dash:1.0.0-rc02"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-session:1.0.0-rc02"
    implementation "androidx.media3:media3-common:1.0.0-rc02"
```

Logcat

```
17:42:01.607  I  Build Config                     : S P 10.0.7 AArch64
17:42:01.607  I  Driver Path                      : /vendor/lib64/egl/libGLESv2_adreno.so
17:42:01.613  I  PFP: 0x016ee190, ME: 0x00000000
17:42:01.663  D  Checking for metadata for AppLocalesMetadataHolderService : Service not found
17:42:01.702  I  [INFO] isPopOver=false, config=true
17:42:01.702  I  updateCaptionType >> DecorView@db543ef[], isFloating=false, isApplication=true, hasWindowDecorCaption=false, hasWindowControllerCallback=true
17:42:01.702  D  setCaptionType = 0, this = DecorView@db543ef[]
17:42:01.761  W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/View;->computeFitSystemWindows(Landroid/graphics/Rect;Landroid/graphics/Rect;)Z (greylist, reflection, allowed)
17:42:01.762  W  Accessing hidden method Landroid/view/ViewGroup;->makeOptionalFitsSystemWindows()V (greylist, reflection, allowed)
17:42:03.151  W  A resource failed to call close. 
17:42:03.152  W  A resource failed to call close. 
17:42:32.581  I  Thread[5,tid=23284,WaitingInMainSignalCatcherLoop,Thread*=0xb4000078297f0570,peer=0x12c42330,"Signal Catcher"]: reacting to signal 3
17:42:32.581  I  
17:42:32.696  I  Wrote stack traces to tombstoned
17:42:43.133  E  ANR in com.example.testapp
                 PID: 20571
                 Reason: executing service com.example.testapp/.MyMusicService
                 Load: 0.0 / 0.0 / 0.0
                 ------ Current CPU Core Info ------
                 - offline : 
                 - online : 0-7
                 - AP Temp = 381
                                              0           1           2           3           4           5           6           7
                 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 scaling_cur_freq        576000      576000      576000      576000      576000      576000     1516800     1516800
                 scaling_governor     schedutil   schedutil   schedutil   schedutil   schedutil   schedutil   schedutil   schedutil
                 scaling_max_freq       1708800     1708800     1708800     1708800     1708800     1708800     2016000     2016000
                 ------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
                 ----- Output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                 some avg10=0.03 avg60=0.25 avg300=0.44 total=2639634764
                 full avg10=0.01 avg60=0.11 avg300=0.14 total=1360303511
                 ----- End output from /proc/pressure/memory -----
                 
                 CPU usage from 0ms to 11068ms later (2023-03-05 17:42:31.989 to 2023-03-05 17:42:43.057):
                   27% 32320/com.zhiliaoapp.musically: 15% user + 12% kernel / faults: 5592 minor 33 major
                   23% 1038/system_server: 9.8% user + 14% kernel / faults: 7237 minor 26 major
                   7.2% 1163/media.codec: 4.1% user + 3.1% kernel / faults: 41149 minor 2 major
                   0.4% 1190/media.swcodec: 0.1% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 23989 minor 1 major
                   5.8% 851/surfaceflinger: 1.7% user + 4.1% kernel / faults: 304 minor
                   5.4% 21899/org.telegram.messenger: 3.1% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 3211 minor 8 major
                   4.6% 8551/transport: 0.8% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 412 minor
                   4.1% 2035/com.android.phone: 2.2% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 4015 minor 165 major
                   3.7% 14760/kworker/u16:8: 0% user + 3.7% kernel / faults: 15 minor
                   3.4% 6678/adbd: 1.1% user + 2.2% kernel / faults: 434 minor
                   1.3% 142/kswapd0: 0% user + 1.3% kernel
                   0.1% 1111/media.extractor: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 6408 minor
                   3% 20149/kworker/u16:0: 0% user + 3% kernel / faults: 6 minor
                   2.5% 2053/com.android.systemui: 1% user + 1.4% kernel / faults: 3179 minor 38 major
                   2.4% 5987/kworker/u16:11: 0% user + 2.4% kernel / faults: 6 minor
                   2.4% 8222/kworker/u16:1: 0% user + 2.4% kernel / faults: 4 minor
                   0% 802/media.hwcodec: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 2775 minor 2 major
                   1.9% 9661/com.pomodrone.app: 1.4% user + 0.5% kernel / faults: 20 minor
                   1.8% 12649/kworker/u16:5: 0% user + 1.8% kernel / faults: 7 minor
                   1.7% 16441/ru.yandex.translate: 1.6% user + 0% kernel / faults: 387 minor
                   1.6% 3135/irq/114-90b6300: 0% user + 1.6% kernel
                   0.6% 16443/com.google.android.apps.tasks: 0.6% user + 0% kernel / faults: 429 minor
                   1.4% 10589/logd: 0.2% user + 1.1% kernel / faults: 18 minor
                   0.4% 30094/android.process.acore: 0.2% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 548 minor
                   0.3% 20571/com.example.testapp: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 3215 minor
                   0.9% 32730/com.android.chrome: 0.9% user + 0% kernel / faults: 560 minor
                   0.9% 4598/com.sec.android.sdhms: 0.2% user + 0.6% kernel / faults: 73 minor
                   0.9% 26391/android.process.acore: 0.8% user + 0% kernel / faults: 507 minor
                   0.8% 22628/com.android.vending: 0.5% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 395 minor 1 major
                   0.6% 9/rcu_preempt: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
                   0.2% 2866/com.android.bluetooth: 0% user + 0.2% kernel / faults: 176 minor
                   0.6% 25771/kworker/u17:2: 0% user + 0.6% kernel
                   0.2% 560/lmkd: 0% user + 0.2% kernel
                   0.4% 10/rcu_sched: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                   0.4% 22441/com.instagram.android: 0.2% user + 0.1% kernel / faults: 20 minor
                   0.4% 27059/kworker/u17:0: 0% user + 0.4% kernel
                   0.3% 12/rcuop/0: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                   0.3% 62/rcuop/6: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                   0.3% 70/rcuop/7: 0% user + 0.3% kernel
                   0% 679/tombstoned: 0% user + 0% kernel
                   0.1% 835/audioserver: 0% user + 0% kernel / faults: 74 minor
                   0.3% 3674/com.samsung.SMT: 0.3% user + 0% kernel / faults: 314 minor
```

I tried do this with rc01 version. But havent got changes. Tried launch on android 12 emulator and get the same issue.

Answer (score 2):

First of all, add this permission since it's internally needed by media3 for network playback:

```
    <uses-permission android:name="android.permission.ACCESS_NETWORK_STATE" />
```

Second of all, you're putting this code in the wrong place, your controller does NOT exist until the future succeeds. Here's the updated code for your onStart:

```
override fun onStart() {
    super.onStart()

    val sessionToken = SessionToken(this, ComponentName(this, MyMusicService::class.java))

    val controllerFuture = MediaController.Builder(this, sessionToken)
        .buildAsync()

    controllerFuture.addListener({

        controller = controllerFuture.get()
        
        findViewById<PlayerControlView>(R.id.player).player = controller
      
        initController()
 
        controller.apply {
            setMediaItem(
            MediaItem.Builder().setMediaId("http://listen.vo.llnwd.net/g3/prvw/9/5/1/1/7/2489571159.mp3").build()
    )

            prepare()
            play()
        }

    }, MoreExecutors.directExecutor())


}
```

Third of all, you shouldn't use 'ExoPlayer' object type at all, Media3 relies on the abstract high-level object type 'Player', so, inside your service class, use this global variable instead:

```
        lateinit var exoPlayer: Player
```

Finally, it's better to use a nullable mediasession variable, in this way:

```
    private var session: MediaSession? = null
```

This should cover all the mishaps in your code. Hope you get it working :)